# ExportAsFixedFormat PDF with dots

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I am trying to export excel files to PDF using VBA. The exporting function works fine, but I am unable to successfully add dots/periods to the filename.

When I use the SaveAs function for the excel spreadsheet, the filename saves correctly. For example:
"(M.003) Bill Johnson.xlsx"

But when I try to export the file to pdf, the filename excludes the portion of "path_id" that comes after the "."; for example:"(M Bill Johnson.pdf"

I'm using Excel 2011 on my Macbook Pro running 10.9.5.

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
'Save file
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim path_id As String

sheet_name = Application.Index(table_mlm.ListColumns("Full Name").DataBodyRange, _
                      Application.Match(consultant_id, table_mlm.ListColumns("Consultant ID").DataBodyRange, 0))

consultant_id = "M.001"

path_id = folder & "September:" & "(" & consultant_id & ")"

wb_report.Sheets(1).Name = sheet_name

wb_report.SaveAs path_id & " " & sheet_name & ".xlsx"

wb_report.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=path_id & sheet_name & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the CHR method and calling up the appropriate ASCII value for a "dot".  Try this:

```
consultant_id = "M" & Chr(46) & "001"
```